# ¿Cómo agregar un contendedor fijo establecido sin que se deforme la imagen?

Tags: css3

Cuando las resoluciones de las imágenes son muy grandes o otras pequeñas causan un deforme en ellas pese a las especificaciones de resoluciones de imágenes responsivas

```
img {
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Esta sigue causando ese defecto en las imágenes.

Dado esos problemas estoy intentando crear un marco, un contenedor fijo establecido con resoluciones establecidas y, que sea responsive pero que no deforme las imágenes.

```css
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; 
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;  
    align-items: center;

    background-color: red;

}

.cell {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto; 

    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;

    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
img {max-width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Baby.gnu-black-800x800.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Mi idea es lograr que se muestre la imagen como resolución máxima de esta manera ya sea de ancho y de alto, de esta manera se observa un post agradable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No comprendo muy bien cual es la pregunta. Ahora mismo veo que tus imágenes se adaptan perfectamente a dispositivos pequeños, respetando su **proporción** y cuando las dimensiones de la pantalla superan el tamaño nativo de la imagen esta no se reescala para que no pixele. ¿Qué es lo que pretendes conseguir?

Comment: @phpMyGuel En si las imágenes se adaptan correctamente, lo que yo deseo es crear un contenedor donde el ancho sea `100%` pero que tenga un alto fijo que se yo unos `400px` porque si yo agrego otra imágen de `2000x2000` está aumenta el alto de su contenedor y, esto causa una mal diseño cuando posteó en el blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#cabecera {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; 
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;  
    align-items: center;

    padding: 10px;

}

.cell {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto; 

    padding: 10px;

    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cabecera" class="row"> 
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Baby.gnu-black-800x800.png"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Probando varias soluciones, la que más me satisface en tu caso es a través de la propiedad `overflow: hidden`. De esta manera mantiene la proporción de la imagen para que no deforme y todo lo que sobrepase del contenedor que has definido para ella pues se oculta.

Esta solución presenta el inconveniente de que pierdes parte de la imagen a favor de preservar la proporción. Si no te importa modificar el **HTML** que tienes yo suelo optar por otra solución que pasa por usar la propiedad `background-image` en vez de usar una etiqueta `<img>` y a través de `background-position: center` que la imagen se recorte de ambos lados al hacerse más pequeña para conseguir que el foco esté en el centro de la imagen en vez de en la izquierda.

```css
#cabecera {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; 
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;  
    align-items: center;

    padding: 10px;
    
    

}

.cell {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto; 

    padding: 10px;

    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Baby.gnu-black-800x800.png');
    background-position: center;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cabecera" class="row"> 
  <div class="cell">
   
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo dedicado.